# CSS not getting inherited

Tags: css

Even thought i have the following rule, it doesn't seem to apply for the footer

```
 a:link, a:visited {
    padding: 0 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

Check [here](http://www.servergreek.com/)

I tried to add the following but doesn't seem to work

```
.footer span  a:link a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: `.footer span a:link a:visited` should be `.footer span a:link, .footer span a:visited`

Comment: also ist a:link really necessary? just do [`.footer span  a`]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule looks for an `a` nested within another `a` within the footer

```
.footer span  a:link a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

You instead want to style the same link in different states (which you separate with a comma):

```
.footer span  a:link,
.footer span a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but why the footer didn't inherit the `a:link, a:visited` and why are specific rules needed for hyperlink in footer

Answer (score 0):

When I tried using

```
.footer span  a {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

it works for me